# git clone: RPC failed; result=22; HTTP code = 408

Tags: git, clone

**Edit: Worked this morning for no clear reason! Great. lol. Some kind of network issue somewhere in the world.

I know this isn't a new problem but when looking around I couldn't find the same case.

Trying to pull from my git repos on my server. I get:

> error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 408
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I've tried running:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

as many people have suggested, but it still hangs up. Any suggestions on how this can be troubleshooted?

Comment: Can it be a problem due to github ? I never had this problem before and it happens really often since last friday.

Comment: Huh. Quite possibly - it worked just fine this morning.

Answer (score 3):

According to my experience, it usually due to poor internet connectivity. Kindly make sure you have good internet connection then retry.

I hope his help someone.